# Putting a Hashmap into itself causes strange behavior

Tags: ruby, hashmap

The following code creates a hashmap and places it inside of itself.

```
hash = {}
hash[hash] = hash
hash.keys.first == hash # true
hash.values.first == hash # true
hash[hash] # nil??
hash.key?(hash) # False
hash[hash.keys.first] # nil???
hash[{}] # nil
```

Can anyone explain these results to me? They seem very counterintuitive.

Comment: Regarding your second line (which causes all the problems), see [Hash#\[\]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), specifically, "key should not have its value changed while it is in use as a key".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutable objects (such as `Array` and `Hash`) are basically improper for
a hash key if you may modify them. In this case, the hash was modified at the point of insertion (since it was inserted into itself!) and has therefore been left in an improper state.

If it is absolutely necessary, you can use [`Hash#rehash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-rehash) to rectify the object state:

```
hash = {}
hash[hash] = hash

hash.rehash # !!!!

hash.keys.first == hash # true
hash.values.first == hash # true
hash[hash] #=> {{...}=>{...}}
hash.key?(hash) # true
hash[hash.keys.first] #=> {{...}=>{...}}
hash[{}] # nil
```

Comment: Any idea why an exception is not raised at line #2? You may want to show the weird return value for that line: (`{{...}=>{...}}`) .